# I want to modify my existing array with new values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I am trying to modify my array every time with new values but not able to achieve that functionality.

So the code for pushing array elements is given like this:

```
const updateYears =  (state, action) => {
      state.dropDownData.years = [...new Set([action.payload])];      
    }
```

And my initial state is like this:

```
const initialState = {  
  dropDownData: {
    programs: [],
    years: [],
  }, 
};
```

The above reducer function is pushing elements inside "years" array.

```
locationSummaries.map((locationSummary)=>dispatch(updateYears(locationSummary.year)));
```

**locationSummaries** is the array of objects containing year as one of the properties.

So when my **year** array contains the values **[2017, 2018, 2019]** and when I am pushing **[2018, 2019]** inside this, I am still having **[2017, 2018, 2019]** inside the original **year** array.
Instead what I want is modified **year** array to **[2018, 2019]**. I believe it is happening because same values are getting pushed inside the array.

So how should I modify my reducer function to achieve this modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If action.payload is array and if you want to modify the array completely, why don't you just assign new array like this:

```
    const updateYears = (state, action) => {
        state.dropDownData.years = action.payload;
    }
```

Comment: actually my payload is array of objects like this [{year: 2021, name:"Mike"}, {year:2022, name: "Vick"}]

Comment: Then this should work: state.dropDownData.years = action.payload.map(item => item.year);

Comment: Great!! @YakoHere It actually worked